# Create multiple dataframes from tuples using read_csv

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, tuples

I have quite a unique problem here. I am trying to create multiple dataframes using read_csv. Assuming I have data for client **details**, their **portfolios** for **Jan** and **Feb**, what is the best way to create multiple dataframes?

I tried the following:

```
mytuple=(['Jan', 'Feb'], details_file, portfolios_file)

for month in mytuple[0]:
    for files in mytuple[1:]:
        df=pd.read_csv(files.format(month))
```

Unfortunately i'm unable to get multiple dataframes e.g dfJanDetails, dfFebDetails, dfJanPortfolio, dfFebPortfolio; I get a single df in the end. What is a good way to achieve my goal?

Also I've referred to the following link but dict can only take in 2 parameters. Thanks in advance!

[generate multiple pandas data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143573/generate-multiple-pandas-data-frames)